# How to get a marker's position when marker is loaded from a .csv file?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map fragment in my app with 2 kinds of markers: the ones that i added with the event OnMapLongClick() and the ones i added from a .csv file. I want to save some details about each coordinates from the marker by starting a new activity when i click on them. The issue that i have is that with the markers added from the .csv file, it always shows the position of the last marker. So my question is, how get i get the position of the corresponded marker that comes from the .csv when i click on it? Can this work by changing the ArrayList with Hashmap?

MapsActivity (the relevant code):

```
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Introdus!");
        markerOptions.draggable(true);

        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        latlngNew = latLng;

        LatLng latlngNew;

    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        if (counter==0) {
            openDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            counter--;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.default_info_title);
        dialog.show();

        Button bt_da = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
        Button bt_nu = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel);

        bt_da.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt_nu.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt_nu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                         dialog.dismiss();

                                     }
                                 }

        );
        bt_da.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter=1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("markerLat", latlngNew.latitude);
                intent.putExtra("markerLong", latlngNew.longitude);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    public void Upload(View view) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "date.csv");
        if (file.exists()) {
        InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
        List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        String line = " ";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read until end of file
            {
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(line.split(",")[0]);
                double lon = Double.parseDouble(line.split(",")[1]);
                latLngList.add(new LatLng(lat, lon));
                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
            }
            for (LatLng pos : latLngList) {
                latlngNew=pos;
                Marker m=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(pos)
                        .title("Din CSV!")
                        .draggable(true)

                );

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, DEFAULT_ZOOM));


            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nu exista fisierul!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    public void Sterge(View view){
        mMap.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like maybe you just need to set `latlngNew` inside the `onMarkerClick()` override.

Comment: But what would it's value be? As for the markers i addes it gets this `intent.putExtra("markerLat", latlngNew.latitude);
                intent.putExtra("markerLong", latlngNew.longitude);` and for the ones from .csv i putted like this `latlngNew=pos;`. I guess i need to manipulate the id's of every entry from csv but don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because you pass to intent `latlngNew` coords:

```
intent.putExtra("markerLat", latlngNew.latitude);
intent.putExtra("markerLong", latlngNew.longitude);
```

which points to the last marker because of loop:

```
for (LatLng pos : latLngList) {
    latlngNew=pos;
    ...
}
```

So, for passing to intent coords of selected marker you should modify `openDialog()` by adding `LatLng` parameter like `openDialog(LatLng coords)` and pass to `openDialog(LatLng coords)` coordinates of selected marker. Something like that:

```
public void openDialog(LatLng coords) {
    //... your code without changes
    bt_da.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter=1;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            // pass coords instead of latlngNew:
            intent.putExtra("markerLat", coords.latitude);
            intent.putExtra("markerLong", coords.longitude);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

and `onMarkerClick()` changed to

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    if (counter==0) {
        // pass marker coordinates here:
        openDialog(marker.getPosition());
    }
    else
    {
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        counter--;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the explanation. Now it works as it should.